# How to keep the first appear unique value for connect rows

Tags: r

I have a df as below. I would like to keep first unique value of `Class` if records are connect to each other. if a repeat value appeared in later record, then we keep another one again (eg: keep A for 1 and 6).

How can I achieve this goal?

[image]

```
df<- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Class = c("A", 
"A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "D", "D"), Score = c(45, 67, 
87, 33, 25, NA, 67, 88, 21, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Under the rules, 10 D is dropped.

Comment: Yes, 10 D is dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative, as a run-length encoding problem:

```r
df |>
  mutate(grp = consecutive_id(Class)) |>
  mutate(.by = grp, Class = c(Class[1], rep("", n() - 1))) |>
  select(-grp)
# # A tibble: 10 × 3
#       ID Class Score
#    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#  1     1 "A"      45
#  2     2 ""       67
#  3     3 ""       87
#  4     4 "C"      33
#  5     5 ""       25
#  6     6 "A"      NA
#  7     7 "B"      67
#  8     8 ""       88
#  9     9 "D"      21
# 10    10 ""       NA
```

The use of `.by=` requires `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer; if you have an older version, change from `mutate(.by=c(..), stuff)` to `group_by(..) |> mutate(stuff) |> ungroup()`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the question properly you can do the following with `dplyr` package:

```
mutate(df, Class = ifelse(lag(Class) != Class | is.na(lag(Class)), Class, NA))
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
      ID Class Score
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 A        45
 2     2 NA       67
 3     3 NA       87
 4     4 C        33
 5     5 NA       25
 6     6 A        NA
 7     7 B        67
 8     8 NA       88
 9     9 D        21
10    10 NA       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R + rle

```
> df$Class[!seq_along(df$Class) %in% head(cumsum(c(1,rle(df$Class)$lengths)),-1)]=NA

   ID Class Score
1   1     A    45
2   2  <NA>    67
3   3  <NA>    87
4   4     C    33
5   5  <NA>    25
6   6     A    NA
7   7     B    67
8   8  <NA>    88
9   9     D    21
10 10  <NA>    NA
```